# Infinitely posting data to server problem with using fetch POST in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, django, django-rest-framework

I am a university student and this is my first time of putting all together of server, api and client sides.

My problem is that first I have created an API using Django-Rest framework.
When I post data to that server using fetch function in JavaScript, it keeps posting that data and does not stop until I close. In the server database, many same data have been created.

I cannot figure out how to fix it. My intention was I want to post the data just once.
Please help me how to do it.

Thank you.

This is my javascript code

```
const testPost = () => {
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/mysite/', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            'player1Hp': 30,
            'player2Hp': 20
        })
    })
        .then(res => {
            return res.json()
        })
        .then(data => console.log(data))
        .catch(error => console.log('ERROR'))
}
```

This is views.py in Django 
[views.py photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjrQO.png)

This is many POST messages in terminal cause of infinite looping [terminal photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9JRJ.png)

This is full screenshoot of script.js  [script.js photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHYaM.png)

HTML just calls script and the rest is just blank.  [index.html photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDyDo.png)

Comment: Please, read the site guide on [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Share your code and you will get an appropriate answer / solution to your problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'll update in my question. Thanks.

Comment: This seems more of a JS issue. Please provide the exact code of your post function and where it's being called.

Comment: I'll provide it as photo. Thanks.